# Scrapy not scraping the percentage sign in a url

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to scrape an image link using Scrapy.

This is the link I'm scraping.

http://www.cars4sale.com/carimages/20TH%FEB%032.JPG

This is how it gets saved in the json file. Notice the percentage sign has been replaced by a blank space.

http://www.cars4sale.com/carimages/20TH FEB 032.JPG

So when I'm displaying this link I get a 404 error because the link is wrong.

How can I get Scrapy to scrape the percentage sign?

Comment: i dont know about scrapy, but i am thinking replacing " "(space) with "%"(percent) in ifnal url will do the work for you

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
urllib.quote(urlWithSpaceInIt)
```

You don't have to do anything to the scrapy stuff. Just quote the url before you go to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the comments, but I don't have enough experience to fix it any of the suggested ways, but they helped me get to the final code that worked for me.

It also turned out that there as a 20 with the % that I didn't notice before.

Here's what I did in JavaScript to add %20 to the URLs.

img src=" + data[i].img.replace(/ | /g,"%20")